# Rootkit scanner with graphical feedback or GUI

Tags: rootkit

There are some rootkitscanners for linux, for example:

- [chkrootkit](http://www.chkrootkit.org/)
- [rkhunter](http://rootkit.nl/projects/rootkit_hunter.html)

But How would I get notified on a desktop?

Is it possible to get an alert, if the scanner found something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the script here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536762/run-rkhunter-regularely-on-a-desktop-system) to get notified by a `zenity` Notification on your desktop

see: [Run rkhunter regularly on a desktop system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536762/run-rkhunter-regularely-on-a-desktop-system)

Answer (score 0):

After installing chkrootkit it adds a crontab within `/etc/cron.daily/chkrootkit` script "I'm using debian wheezy"

each chkrootkit daily execution logs inside a `$LOG_DIR/log.today`, you can then create a daemon that tracks changes within the log file and send you email or run something to alert you.

Comment: Ok, so How would you create such an alert on the screen? Ubuntu desktop usually doesn't send emails

Comment: sudo apt-get install notify-osd then notify-send "Hello there !"

Comment: cat $LOG_DIR/log.today | grep "not infected" if response is something else then you've to worry a little bit

Comment: I guess, I have to enable check daily in `/etc/chkrootkit.conf` and then add your suggestion somewhere. Where?

Comment: add a crontab at /etc/cron.daily/alert-chkrootkit within you can put the tiny grep code.

Comment: If you want to provide a thorough answer, you should edit your answer and add a description how you add this. Askubuntu is a site for desktop-users that normally are not so firm on the console some don't even know how to open a console

Comment: So I want to put this command somewhere: `sudo rkhunter --checkall --report-warnings-only | while read OUTPUT; do notify-send "$OUTPUT"; done
` But where?