# Run rkhunter regularly on a desktop system

Tags: security, cron, dbus, libnotify, rkhunter

I want to get a warning on my desktop when rkhunter finds something odd on my system.

I whitelisted some files and dirs that seem ok in `/etc/rkhunter.conf` so I get no warnings anymore.

Now I want to put this command somewhere:

```
sudo rkhunter --checkall --report-warnings-only | while read OUTPUT; do notify-send "$OUTPUT"; done
```

I know how to use `cron` but that doesn't work, cause my computer is running at irregular times, so where do I have to put this so it is executed once a day **but not during system-boot?** Optimal would be 30 Minutes after startup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running command at certain time or after that as soon as possible](http://askubuntu.com/questions/537077/running-command-at-certain-time-or-after-that-as-soon-as-possible)

Comment: [That page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/537077/running-command-at-certain-time-or-after-that-as-soon-as-possible) suggests using anachron, but that will not run the command lets say 30 minutes after boottime, It will run directly after boot, if it didn't run this day already

Comment: Use the same command in your answer for the anacron entry. That way you get the scheduling and the reliability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Run at startup, display with `zenity`

Create a file `/usr/local/sbin/rkhunter-check` and make it executable:

```
sudo touch /usr/local/sbin/rkhunter-check
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/rkhunter-check
```

Edit the file `gksu gedit /usr/local/sbin/rkhunter-check`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export DISPLAY=:0
MAINUSER="$(awk -F: '$3==1000{print $1}' /etc/passwd)"
LOG=/tmp/.rkhunter-warnings
rm -f $LOG
touch $LOG
rkhunter --checkall --report-warnings-only  | while read OUTPUT; do 
  if [ "$OUTPUT" != "" ]; then
    OUTPUT="${OUTPUT//[\`\"\']/}"
    echo "$OUTPUT">>$LOG
  fi
done
if [ "$(cat $LOG)" = "" ]; then
  #like this there is always a notification, even if there is no warning, it will show an empty notification.
  echo "#no warnings">$LOG
fi
if [ "$(cat $LOG)" != "" ]; then
  su $MAINUSER -c 'zenity --text-info --width 800 --title "Rkhunter warnings" < '"$LOG"
fi
```

If the rkhunter run generates any output (only warnings), this script will show up as a scrollable window with the rkhunter output.

1. #### create a systemd startup script

   Create the script `/etc/systemd/system/rkhunter.service`:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=starts rkhunter and displays any findings with zenity

   [Service]
   TimeoutStartSec=infinity
   ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 1800
   ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/rkhunter-check

   [Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
   ```

   Update systemd with:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl enable rkhunter
   sudo systemctl start rkhunter
   ```
2. #### start by `/etc/rc.local`

   On systems without `systemd` call the script at runtime in `/etc/rc.local` and put a sleep before the whole command:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
   ```

   Add this  command before the last line in `/etc/rc.local` that contains `exit 0`:

   ```
   sleep 1800 && /usr/local/sbin/rkhunter-check &
   ```

Both solutions will wait 30 minutes before executing the rkhunter check **as root**.

---

You can also combine this solution with the notify-send solution, because in case there are no warnings, a zenity dialog is not perfect. a notification would suffice in that case

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export DISPLAY=:0
MAINUSER="$(awk -F: '$3==1000{print $1}' /etc/passwd)"
LOG=/tmp/.rkhunter-warnings
echo ""> $LOG
rkhunter --checkall --report-warnings-only  | while read OUTPUT; do 
  if [ "$OUTPUT" != "" ]; then
    OUTPUT="${OUTPUT//[\`\"\']/}"
    echo "$OUTPUT">>$LOG
  fi
done
if [ "$(cat $LOG)" = "" ]; then
  MAINUSER="$(awk -F: '$3==1000{print $1}' /etc/passwd)"
  if [ -r "/home/$MAINUSER/.dbus/Xdbus" ]; then
    . "/home/$MAINUSER/.dbus/Xdbus"
  fi
  su $MAINUSER -c $"notify-send \"rkhunter: no warnings\""
fi
if [ "$(cat $LOG)" != "" ]; then
  su $MAINUSER -c 'zenity --text-info --width 800 --title "Rkhunter warnings" < '"$LOG"
fi
```

---

source: [How to run a script during boot as root](https://askubuntu.com/a/290100/34298)

Comment: Why `su <user> -c` instead of `sudo -u <user>`? The `sudo` way lends itself to one less set of quotes and less escaping. Also, `getent passwd 1000` instead of grepping through `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Ah. Presumably you have to set the DISPLAY variable. Here's how I used it in one script: `/usr/bin/sudo -u $user DISPLAY=$seat notify-send --urgency critical "$MESSAGE"`

Comment: Usually it's `:0`. But you can parse the output of `w` to get the main display: `w -hsf | grep -v pts` should have the display or the tty in second field, and the displays are of the form `:[0-9]+`. Here's the script I used it in on [Github](https://github.com/murukeshm/scripts/blob/master/idlekiller).

Answer (score 1):

### Solution with `anachron` and `notify-send`

The answer to the problem is [anachron](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/anacron.8.html) that executes commands automatically **as root**, where root needs access to the dbus session of the main user.

### 1. Give root access to your desktop session (as user)

To let the root user access the default user's desktop, you first need to set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable. By default cron does not have access to the variable that changes every system start. To remedy this put the following script in your home directory and call it `~/dbus-session-export`

```
#!/bin/sh
touch ~/.dbus/Xdbus
chmod 600 ~/.dbus/Xdbus
env | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > ~/.dbus/Xdbus
echo 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' >> ~/.dbus/Xdbus
exit 0
```

Give it executable rights:

```
chmod +x ~/dbus-session-export
```

And call it in your startup programs.
This will create/update the file `~/.dbus/Xdbus` containing the required Dbus evironment variable for anachron to use at each system boot.

### 2. Cron script (as root)

Put a script in the  folder `/etc/cron.daily/` and make it executable:

```
sudo touch /etc/cron.daily/rkhunter-check
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/rkhunter-check
```

Edit the file `gksu gedit /etc/cron.daily/rkhunter-check`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sleep 1800 # wait 30 minutes in case the script is called directly at boot
MAINUSER="$(awk -F: '$3==1000{print $1}' /etc/passwd)"
if [ -r "/home/$MAINUSER/.dbus/Xdbus" ]; then
    . "/home/$MAINUSER/.dbus/Xdbus"
fi
su $MAINUSER -c 'notify-send "starting rkhunter scan... "'
rkhunter --checkall --report-warnings-only | while read OUTPUT; do
if [ "$OUTPUT" != "" ]; then
    OUTPUT="${OUTPUT//[\`\"\']/}"
    su $MAINUSER -c $"notify-send \"rkhunter: $OUTPUT\""
fi
done
```

This will run the script every day once and if the rkhunter run generates any output (only warnings), this script will show up as a notification for each warning in the top right of your screen **as user**

---

Source:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron
- [how to create a notification on the screen initiated by root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162492/create-a-notification-on-the-screen-initiated-by-root)

Comment: You can also combine this solution with the zenity solution, because in case there are no warnings, a zenity dialog is not perfect. a notification would suffice in that case

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cron`. Edit with:

```
crontab -e
```

for more info on how to use `cron`,
follow this link:

[crotab-tutorial](http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial)

Comment: sure, cause I thought that was too obvious and therefore clear cause I had the tag in there from the beginning. I waited some days if you enhance your question before I downvoted. Your Answer lacks of a description how to add this. If you would include the most important part from the tutoriat for this case, it would enhance your answer, though it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: If I think about it, I could use cron: I would have to add the rkhunter run every hour, and check before, if the boottime is long enough in the past using `uptime -s`