# Cron Monthly job works randomly using `0 0 1 * *`

Tags: cron

I have this `sudo crontab -e` job entry I setup in April then forgot about:

```
0   0   1   *   *     /bin/journalctl --vacuum-size=200M
```

What it does is keep down the size of `journalctl` files each month so they are only 200 MB in size (or thereabouts).

I followed these instructions:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/87472/how-to-create-a-cron-job-that-runs-on-the-first-day-of-month

However I only received the following e-mail on January 1st, 2019 saying the job has finally run. I don't recall receiving an e-mail after setting the job up in April 2018. Why is this monthly job only running on New Year's Eve? :

[image: cron monthly journalctl.png]

(... SNIP ...)

[image: cron monthly journalctl end.png]

At the very end it says 1.2 GB of space was freed. However it means about 1 GB was wasted until the job ran on New Year's Eve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running command at certain time or after that as soon as possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537077/running-command-at-certain-time-or-after-that-as-soon-as-possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the job only ran on New Year's Eve is all the other first days of the month your machine was shut off at the stroke of midnight.

The easiest way is to not use `sudo crontab -e` but rather create a bash script in the directory `/etc/cron.monthly`. Make sure the script filename doesn't contain a `.` in it. Filenames containing a `.` such as `Monthly job.cron` or `MonthlyUpdate.sh` will not run.

In this case use:

```bsh
sudo -H gedit /etc/cron.monthly/journal_vacuum
```

Insert these lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
#
# NAME: journal_vacuum
# DESC: Reduce size of system journals (journalctl) each month.
# DATE: January 9, 2019.

# NOTE: Replaces `0 0 1 * * /bin/journalctl --vacuum-size=200M` which
#       which only runs if machine is turned on at midnight.

/bin/journalctl --vacuum-size=200M
```

Save the file and exit `gedit`. Make the script executable using:

```bsh
sudo chmod a+x /etc/cron.monthly/journal_vacuum
```

Now the first time the machine is turned on each month, be it 1st day of month at 7:00am or even 2nd day of month the `cron` job will run.

---

### Update 1

Once per month is unpredictable. The cron job was setup on January 9, 2019 and then ran on January 30, 2019:

[image: monthly cron job.png]

Hopefully the cron job runs again on Feb 1, 2019 as anticipated!

---

### Update 2

The script in `/etc/cron.monthly/` did not run on February 1, 2019. Digging deeper I found this explanation:

- [[SOLVED] cron.monthly not running - everything else is](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/cron-monthly-not-running-everything-else-is-4175461238/)

Following the link's explanation I discovered:

```bsh
$ sudo cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.monthly
20190130
```

Therefore with `sudo` powers I used:

```bsh
rick@alien:~$ sudo -i
root@alien:~# echo 20190101 > /var/spool/anacron/cron.monthly
root@alien:~# exit
```

Now cron believes that last time `monthly` jobs were run is January 1, 2019.

Time to reboot and test...

---

### Update 3

After reboot an email was almost instantly sent:

```bsh
Anacron <XxxxxXxxxx999@gmail.com>    7:45 AM (3 minutes ago)
to root, bcc: XxxxxXxxxx999

/etc/cron.monthly/journal_vacuum:
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals on disk.
```

Now we can see:

```bsh
$ sudo cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.monthly
20190203
```

The last step is to replace `20190203` with `20190201` using technique in **Update 2**.

Comment: This answer relies on `anacron`, and `anacron` is not installed by default using the server installer.

Comment: If you want to avoid rebooting to trigger `anacron` you can also simply delete `/var/spool/anacron/cron.monthly` and then run `sudo anacron -dsq` or just `sudo anacron`. Or use `sudo anacron -f` to have it run _now_ regardless of any timestamps. On `systemd` systems (like Ubuntu 18.04 desktop) `anacron` is run by systemd units. See `systemctl cat anacron.service anacron.timer`. The timer unit starts the service unit every hour which in turn runs `/usr/sbin/anacron -dsq` and that would be the "workaround command" if rebooting isn't convenient.

Comment: @PerlDuck Thank you. Your elaborate comment could be posted as a self-answered question :) PS you nominated to close this question last month so it's kind you would comment today.

Comment: You're welcome. But the question _How to [Manually run an Anacron Job_](https://askubuntu.com/q/761658/504066) has already been asked ;-)

Comment: @PerlDuck True but this question is specific about cron's `0 0 1 * *` and how it works best for 24/7 server but not so well for home users who don't have machine turned on the first of the month at midnight. You will find `0 0 1 * *` littered throughout the internet as an example of running first of month. I think the internet search will mislead many non-server users like it did myself for 8 month ends.

Comment: I think you are right. Since I learned about those `cron.Xly` directories I didn't add any jobs to regular crontabs because my machine isn't up 24/7 either and `anacron` is just perfect for this scenario.

Comment: @PerlDuck I'm open to suggestions for a new title to keep this from being closed as a duplicate....eg `Why /etc/cron.* directories aren't in Ubuntu Server and are better for for non-server users than crontab`